# Fail to initialize resources in android app - then NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So, I have this android application and even some users. As I have a crash report system, I can see when someone's app crashes and the cause.

It appears that, though rarely, the app crashes randomly with NullPointerException when it tries to change some attributes(rotation, text, etc..). I make sure everything is set first thing in the onViewCreated method(using Fragments) like this:

```
private TextView orientationView;

orientationView = this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.orientationView);
```

Using this ^^ example, I then try to hide/show this view and get an exception as it appears to be null sometimes, which is what I struggle to figure out why.

```
orientationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // app crashes when orientationView is null
```

Being a newbie in android development, I am not sure if it is a good practice, but in some of the fragments, I set all the previously initialized resources to null in the onDestroyView method, but the one that crashes the most doesn't have this method implemented, which make me to believe that somehow the resources are just not found/initialized in some rare occasions and I fail to change them later with an exception.

Could someone help me figure this out :)   (more description could be provided, if needed)

Comment: Where is this `orientationView` added exactly? In the host `Activity`'s view or in the `Fragment`'s view?

Comment: This specifically is in a fragment, but all of them fragments are supposed to be on the Main activity, just switching one another.

Comment: If the view is in a fragments layout, you should use `view.findViewById(...)` in your fragment's `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: Sure, I will try it, but what is the difference really between View, Fragment Activity, Context...?